# C compiler checking for overlap in multiple enum

Tags: c, enums, overlap

Does anyone knows if it is possible to get the compiler to check if two enums overlap?

We have several SW packages, were each has an enum with eeprom address definitions
Is there a way to get the compiler to combine these and check for overlaps?

```
typedef enum
{
    DEF_A = 1,
    DEF_B = 2
} Enum1;

typedef enum
{
    DEF_C = 1,
    DEF_D = 3
} Enum2;

enum 
{
    Enum1, 
    Enum2
};
```

=> Generate compile error since DEF_1 and DEF_3 has the same value

Comment: `enum 
{
    Enum1, 
    Enum2
};` shouldn't compile. No, C is a language without reflection. To "reflect" (inspect) C code itself you have to use another tool.

Comment: I think this will be a manual task. It is part of Configuration Management and assigns and addresses to the packages.

Comment: What is the rule for checking which enums may "overlap" and which may not? In you example you use a value of 1 as a criteria for detecting overlaping. If your enum use a naming convention (eg DEF_XXX) for the values you might simple grep all of them in the source files and ensure they each have a unique value.

Comment: Bad naming from my part...
The rule is if two defines have the same value it should result in an error.
Naming with numbers cannot be trusted. 
Since its different people, inventing names, not paying attention to the naming convention and coding rules

Comment: There isn't a way to use an enumeration constant without specifying it explicitly. If you know what they all are, you can use static assertions to compare them. That should at least produce a compiler warning if violated, maybe a compiler error if you are lucky.

Comment: Im not sure I understand how to do that...

Comment: that's not the case, the problem is that you are defining `Enum1` and `Enum2` as custom types and then you redeclare them as items of enum! which will not be acceptable by the compiler and gives you an Error

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if it is possible to get the compiler to check if two enums overlap?

Yes, I know, and no, it is not possible. For the same reason you won't find a compiler warning about two different integers being assigned 0: it's perfectly okay.

You should understand that each enumeration list is nothing but a mapping of identifiers to values. Different identifiers are allowed to map to the same value, even in the same enumeration list:

```
enum count { ZIP = 0, ZILCH = 0, NADA = 0, ZERO = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE };
```

is not a problem. If you want to avoid identifiers with the same value, what you can do is place them all in the *same* enum list and *do not assign* any of them, or maximally the first.

If you need to check this across more than one enum list, you need to look for solutions outside the C language.

Comment: Ok, that was what I though

Answer (score 0):

With a good compiler such as gcc (`-Woverride-init`), you may be able to create a "super array" including all known enumeration constants in the project in the form of designated initializers:

```
const int dummy[] = 
{
  [DEF_A] = 0,
  [DEF_B] = 0,
  [DEF_C] = 0,
  [DEF_D] = 0,
};
```

The gcc compiler will now poke you in case of duplicates:

```
x|warning: initialized field overwritten [-Woverride-init]|
x|warning: (near initialization for 'dummy[1]') [-Woverride-init]|
```

where x is the line number where the value `dummy[1]` was encountered for the second time (the `[DEF_C]` line).

Comment: Smart solution... :-)
Unfortunately I do not know future declarations made by others...

I might use it in some Unit testing were I build up a the structure with python...

Comment: @Conny You _could_ enforce all enum declarations to be done inside evil macro lists and then have another evil macro generate the above array. Not really something I would recommend anyone to do, but quite possible.